# How to use correctly js parseInt?

Tags: javascript, parseint

It doesn't work correctly see below and how it should be

`parseInt(19.31 * 100) // 1930`

should be

`parseInt(19.31 * 100) // 1931`

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` at all, given you're already starting with a number?

Comment: use `Math.round()` instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: parseInt rounds the number, maybe you should go for parseFloat()

Comment: @ChrisG — There is no point is putting a number into a function designed to turn strings into numbers. It will just implicitly convert the number to a string and then the function will convert it back.

Comment: @ChrisG He *wants* to round the number.

Comment: It's because `parseInt()` accepts a string. If the argument is not a string, it is converted to one using the `.toString` operation.  `(19.31 * 100).toString()` is `1930.9999999999998` and if you parse that to an integer, it's `1930`.

Comment: Dirty trick: `parseInt((19.31*100).toFixed(2))`

Comment: I need this number format multiplied by 100, example: 19.31 to 1931, 19.00 to 1900

Comment: Or just use `Math.round` :)